# How to resize a feature and prevent it from scaling when zooming in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers

I have initialized a custom OpenLayers 3 map (used to show houses for sale in the neighborhood) with an image as the map.

Then, I create additionnal features and layers dynamically for each house (each feature's anchor is set as the middle of its image).

I've been trying to use the `size` property when initializing the feature, but what it does is **crop** the image instead of resizing it.

I think I have seen the `resize` function for layers somewhere in OL2, but I can't find it in OL3... would that kind of function achieve the result I want?

There's also the problem that the features are scaling way too big when zoomed out of the map, and scaling down too small when zoomed in a lot. Is there a way to specify the feature's coordinates then do some kind of invisible margins/padding around it to prevent it from going too big or too small (some kind of static size) ?

Here is the actual behavior of features (the feature seen here is the black house):
[image: Zoomed out] - Next: Perfect size, the house should be way smaller when zoomed out though (as seen on the first picture).[image: Perfect zoom] -  The house should've stayed bigger, instead of scaling down again in this last picture.[image: Zoomed in too much].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you use an `ol.style.Icon`. `ol.style.Icon` has a `scale` [option](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.style.Icon.html?unstable=true) that you can use to scale the icon image.

For example, if you want to scale an image down you'll use something like this:

```js
var style = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    url: 'http://example.com/icon.png',
    scale: 0.5,
    // …
  })
});
```

Now, if you want different `scale` values based on the current resolution, you can pass a style function to the vector layer:

```js
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Icon({
  url: 'http://example.com/icon.png',
  // …
});

var styles = [new ol.style.Style({
  image: iconStyle
})];

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    // "func" is your function that gives you a scale for a resolution
    var scale = func(resolution);
    iconStyle.setScale(scale);
    return styles;
  })
});
```

Note that, as an optimization, the above code reuses the `ol.style.Icon` object, the `ol.style.Style` object and the array of styles, to avoid creating objects each time the style function is called.

Comment: I finally got it to work, thanks to you. I've adapted your code a little bit: The source needs to include the feature itself: `source: new ol.source.Vector({features:[iconFeature]})`, otherwise nothing is inserted within the layer (for some reason, probably related to the geometry element of the feature).